# gcov: cannot open graph file

Tags: c, macos, gcov

I am trying to use gcov. I have this simple file a.c:

```
int main() {
   return 0;
}
```

So I do

```
gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage a.c -o a
./a
gcov a.c
```

and I get

```
a.gcno:cannot open graph file
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm under Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: For the record, I find it utterly appalling that the compiler should fail silently here. Grr!

Answer (score 12):

By default on Lion, "gcc" is not gcc. It's LLVM. And it doesn't support generating test coverage data.

If you run `gcc-4.2 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage a.c -o a` instead that will use a real gcc, and it'll probably work.

Comment: My XCode install didn't have a link for gcc-4.2. However, the tip below about calling 'clang' solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you are running the command from the same directory as the source file? You must be in the same directory, unless you specify the -o flag. Try:

```
gcov -o a.c
```

Comment: This is not true.  You need to be in the same directory as the **gcda file**, which is typically in the same directory as the object files.  gcov can figure out where the source is from those files.

Comment: In some cases the gcda file is not generated, and running this command from a different directory shows that the gcno file cannot be open. Using the -o corrects the issue and allows gcov to then display the proper error message that the gcda file is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `clang` instead of `gcc`. I had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8622293/293511), and using `clang` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Often this happens when the version of `gcov` you're running doesn't match the version of GCC used to compile the application. On some systems, package managers have odd practices in how they link GCC and `gcov`. For example on many systems `gfortran` is the same as `gfortran-5` but `gcov` might be something old and crusty.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following on `Mac 10.8.4`:

- Installed via xcode the command line tools:

[image]

- wrote [this example](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_8.html) code from the gcc website:

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>  
  main() 
  {  
     int i, total; total = 0; 
     for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        total += i; 
     if (total != 45) 
        printf ("Failure\n"); 
     else 
        printf ("Success\n"); 
  }
  ```
- Compiling using the real GCC `gcc-mp-4.7  -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage tmp.c`
- And using GCC's gcov: `gcov-mp-4.7 -b tmp.c` will give you this output:

  ```
  File 'tmp.c'
  Lines executed:87.50% of 8
  Branches executed:100.00% of 4
  Taken at least once:75.00% of 4
  Calls executed:50.00% of 2
  Creating 'tmp.c.gcov'
  ```