# cannot open graph file gcov with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, profiling, ubuntu-12.04, gcov

I am using gcov as my code coverage tool for my c++ project with gcc (currently 4.6.3 but soon to be 4.8) on Ubuntu 12.04 and am getting the error cannot open graph file. What does this error mean? And how do I get rid of it so that I can see my code coverage?

I've seen other solutions to this problem the most popular being to use clang ([gcov: cannot open graph file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816839/gcov-cannot-open-graph-file/8630169#8630169)) instead of gcc but I can't switch compilers, I have to use gcc so that is not a workable solution for me. Plus, the documentation on gcov says that it should work with gcc.

Another solution was to fix a configuration file (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1547252) but I'm not sure what configuration file this user is speaking of so if that is my problem as well I don't know how to fix it

my .gcda and .gcno files are correctly being generated in my obj directory

beyond going into my top directory where I compile my code and doing gcov *.c I'v also tried 
gcov -o directory/to/obj *.c
and
gcov -o directory/to/obj *.gcda
and
gcov -o directory/to/obj *.gcno

but none of these solutions work; i still get the cannot open graph file error.

Any help or advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The above problem is due to absence of `.gcda and .gcno file in the directory where your source code present` .

So my suggestion is 1st copy `one .gcda and .gcno file of particular .c file in your source code where your .c resides then execute gcov filename.c`.

If you get coverage ,then try to soft link all your .gcda and .gcno to source code if dont want to copy from obj directory then as u stated problem ll be solved

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify few of the things that you were doing wrong.

First: you always tried to specify *.gcda, *.gcno, *.c etc after obj directory path, which is totally wrong.
What you need to do is to specify it as "-o path/to/obj/ " (path to directory)

You can even specify path to gcda file of that particular c/c++ source file and specify path to obj directory in "-o" flag to get the report for that file.

And if you use gcovr instead of gcov for your reports then you can get all the kind of reports by specifying only the root directory (directory above src & obj) with "-r -root=ROOT" flag.
Refer to this user [guide](http://gcovr.com/guide.html#gcovrCommand) for details on gcovr.